# Xdebug remote.host IP changed when VPN Is active

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using PhpStorm with a docker container on a MacBook (Sierra 10.12.5) as my dev environment. When I'm not connected to my company VPN, the PhpStorm debug connection in PhpStorm looks like this:

```
docker://docker.companyurl.com/docker-developer:latest/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=192.168.10.1 /opt/project/testscript.php
```

This works fine, breakpoints are working and everything is good.

However, once the VPN connects (which I need to do if I'm accessing internal databases), the connect string changes to:

```
docker://docker.companyurl.com/docker-developer:latest/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=10.75.5.4 /opt/project/testscript.php
```

No breakpoints get triggered and the scripts completes without any debug session starting.

Does anyone know why the IP address changes? I've tried manually specifying the correct IP in the Xdebug options within PhpStorm, but instead of overriding the command line option it duplicates it, and it still doesn't break.

I am not able to work productively as long as this goes on, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: *"but instead of overriding the command line option it duplicates it,"* AFAIK it's OK -- the last one should override first one. *", and it still doesn't break."* Please collect xdebug log and verify to what IP address:port it tries to connect in such case.

Comment: In a situation where you are connecting to a vpn, your laptop is getting a new ip address. Depending on the vpn that you are using, that vpn software may very well be actively denying connections to your normal ip address on your local network. If you use the original ip address string, does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem is that phpstorm tries to read the IP address and other vars at run time-- if you're on the VPN it picks up your VPN-assigned IP instead of the actual IP.

So what appears to be a solution at the moment is:

1) open phpstorm preferences / Languages and Frameworks / PHP / Debug / Advanced Settings. Uncheck the box for "Pass configuration options through command line"

2) open phpstorm preferences / Languages and Frameworks / PHP, then click the `...` near the PHP CLI interpreter. Click the `...` near the Additional / Configuration Options item, and add a new param for `xdebug.remote_host` with a value of `192.168.10.1`